# ActiveDirectory error only from staging server

Tags: c#, vb.net, active-directory

I am receiving the following error when attempting to login to my application. It works locally but I receive this error when using the remote server.

**Error**

```
The format of the specified domain name is invalid.
System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryOperationException: The format of the specified domain name is invalid.
```

**Stack Trace**

```
[ActiveDirectoryOperationException: The format of the specified domain name is invalid.]
System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext.GetDnsDomainName(String domainName) +195
System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext.GetLoggedOnDomain() +785
System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext.IsContextValid(DirectoryContext context, DirectoryContextType contextType) +186
System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext.isDomain() +66
System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetDomain(DirectoryContext context) +98
PQI.ActiveDirectoryPasswordExpires..ctor() in [PATH REMOVED]\vb\ActiveDirectoryPasswordExpires.vb:11
PQI._Default.UserIsSuper(String username, String password) in [PATH REMOVED]\Default.aspx.vb:104
PQI._Default.rb_Login_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in [PATH REMOVED]\Default.aspx.vb:20
Telerik.Web.UI.RadButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +311
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3707
```

This is a standard VB.Net application with nothing special, just checking AD to authenticate logged in users (and as the stack trace suggests, Super Users if they belong to a specific AD group). Has anyone run across this issue before? What am I doing wrong?

The application on the staging server is in its own .Net 4.0/Integrated app pool.

To answer Matt Wilko's question, the LDAP string is generated dynamically. The first line of the New() function below is what triggers the error.

```
Public Sub New()
    Dim currentDomain As Domain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain
    Dim root As DirectoryEntry = currentDomain.GetDirectoryEntry
    Using (currentDomain)
        Using (root)
            Me.policy = New ActiveDirectoryDomainPolicy(root)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: what does the LDAP string look like?

Comment: @Matt: I've edited the question to include the answer to your question. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: So can you show the *actual* string produced in both cases as I suspect this is being formed incorrectly